# conditional display for multiple fields - JSF 2.0 / Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

What is the best strategy for conditionally displaying multiple elements (for example a list of fields that depends on a bean value)?

Possible solutions I thought of:

1. JSTL `<c:if ... >` clause. From what I
   understand using JSTL with JSF is
   discouraged
2. Using the "rendered"
   attribute of most components.
   Unfortunately when I have to deal
   with a lot of fields it becomes
   clumsy to set them on each one...
3. Putting the elements on a container
   and setting the rendered attribute
   on the container

Option 3 seems the most sensible but I don't know what component to use to wrap those fields. It needs to be a component that doesn't affect the layout...

I could use a span as a wrapper and set a CSS visible property, but the fields will still be rendered, just invisible.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

Here's some actual layout code. I've tried both `<h:panelGroup>` & `<ui:fragment>`. Using any of those tags will put all my fields in a single `<td>`, which I admit, it makes sense because I'm putting a single top level element in my `panelGrid`.

The only thing that works the way I want is #2 from the list above.

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <!-- fields if person -->
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{createEntity.entityType eq 'fizica'}">
            <h:outputLabel value="Prenume: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.person.firstName}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Nume familie: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.person.familyName}"  />
            <h:outputLabel value="CNP: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.person.cnp}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Date carte identitate: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.person.idCardInfo}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Cetatenie: " />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.person.country}" />
        </ui:fragment>

        <!--  fields for company  -->
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{createEntity.entityType eq 'juridica'}">           
            <h:outputLabel value="Denumire firma"  />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.company.name}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="CUI"  />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.company.cui}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Registrul Comertului"  />
                <h:inputText value="#{createEntity.company.regCommerceNo}" />
        </ui:fragment>
    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I fail to see why using the `rendered` attribute is more clumsy than `c:if`.

Comment: @BalusC: Because if I have for example 5 fields + 5 labels that I want to show conditionally, this means I have to copy-paste the "render" condition 10 times. That's clumsy to me...

Comment: Why not just replace `c:if test` by `ui:fragment rendered`? You already wrapped it with JSTL `c:if` tag, you just have to wrap it by a suitable JSF tag instead.

Comment: Just have two panelgrids and put `rendered` on panelgrids.

Comment: @BalusC: Now I'm having one of those "doh" moments :). Thanks!

Comment: @BalusC, it's a requirement to love BalusC's comments/responses here on stackoverflow! Within the last year, most of my JSF knowledge/solutions have come because of BalusC!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rendered is the recommended way to display (or not) a component.

If you can group them together, then setting the rendered attribute of the container is perfectly valid. I'd do that in preference to setting the rendered attribute on each individual component.

The only minor disadvantage is if the display is dynamic (you change the backing bean value), and you need to redisplay the container, it doesn't exist. You need to wrap the container in another container which you then reRender.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `h:panelGroup` as a container for this.  It has a rendered property and will result in a span (by default).

Comment: It won't output anything if you don't set any attributes which has to end up in HTML.

Comment: Correct.  I meant that if an html tag is generated it will be a span by default (can be changed via the layout attribute).  There is indeed nothing generated if no id/style/styleClass attribute is specified and if no client behavior is defined for the component.

Answer (score 1):

I had to resort to using  because when I wrapped my column values in another component (like ui:fragment, or h:panelGroup) to use the rendered for that component the panelGrid treated the entire ui fragment as one column which really messed up my table.

```
<c:if test="#{myBean.displayThese}">
   <!-- columns to display for this condition -->
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{!myBean.displayThese}">
   <!-- other stuff to display -->
</c:if>
```

surprisingly, `<c:otherwise>` didn't seem to work for me though.

Comment: perfect. best Solution is using "c:if" .

Answer (score 0):

ugly, but maybe working for you, via conditional style:

```
<h:component value="foo" style="#{!myBean.displayFoo ? 'display: none;' : ''}" />
```

Answer (score -2):

if you request is a conditional with the value of your variable of your database:

```
<c:if test="#{myObject.mycolumnTableDB==value1}">
   <!-- columns to display for this condition -->
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{myObject.mycolumnTableDB==value2}">
   <!-- other stuff to display -->
</c:if>
```

Comment: This is not substantially different from Lance's answer from two years ago.